# Passing mulitple parameters to dynamic route in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, dynamic-routing

I am trying the first project with Svelte and I have a situation like this:

I fetch a list of results from an API like here:

```
# Page with a list of items

<script context="module">
  export const load = async ({ page, fetch }) => {
    const res = await fetch(`url`);
    const items = await res.json();
    return {
      props: {
        items,
      },
    };
  };
</script>

<script>
  export let items;
</script>

{#each items.data as { id, item, href }}
    <li>
      <a href="/page/{href}">{ item }</a>
    </li>
{/each}
```

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to the next (dynamic) route so that `href` is the `slug` and `id` is the `id` for fetching the item details from the API like here:

```
# Page with a single item

<script context="module">
  export const load = async ({ page, fetch }) => {
    const slug = page.params.slug; <-- I can get this
    const res = await fetch(`url/${page.id}`); <-- but not this
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
      props: {
        data,
      },
    };
  };
</script>
```

I apologise for my ignorance but I am really struggling and I do not know how to address this exactly. I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2):

Most recent version of SvelteKit simplifies this further (December 2023).

File structure like so:

```
src/
└── routes/
    └── [siteId]/
        └── [projectId]/
            ├── +page.server.ts
            └── +page.svelte
```

Gives you access like so:

`+page.server.ts`:

```
// +page.server.ts
export async function load({params}) {
    const siteId = params['siteId'] as string
    const projectId = params['projectId'] as string

    return {siteId, projectId}
}
```

`+page.svelte`:

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    export let data

    const siteId = data.siteId
    const projectId = data.projectId
</script>
<p>siteId: {siteId}, projectId: {projectId}</p>
```

Now you can navigate to `http://localhost:5173/some-site-id/some-project-id` and pull out the params as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for this

One is to have a second 'slug', this would mean you have a file structure like `/page/[slug]/[id].svelte`, in that case you can simply do `const { slug, id } = page.params;` and your anchor becomes `<a href="/page/{href}/{id}">`.  This has the disadvantage that you still have to find a way to handle if people browse to `/page/{href}` without passing an id.

Another option is to pass the id as query parameter, here your anchor would be `<a href="/page/{href}?id={id}">` the files are like what you have and you get the query parameter as follows `const id = page.query.get('id')`.  Here you still have to handle if people come to this page without having an id, but in that case `id` will be undefined, so it's perhaps a touch easier to handle.

**Update 3 Feb 2023**

SvelteKit has changed a bit since this answer.  The most important one being that the load function is no longer in a script with 'context="module"' but instead in it's own file.

The load function itself for both options still looks very similar:

```js
export const load = (async ({ params, url }) => {
  // option 1
  const { key, title } = params;
  // option 2  
  const title = params.title;
  const id = url.searchParams.get('id');
}
```