# Svelte Dynamic Route Param - Passing Multiple Params?

Tags: dynamic, parameters, routes, svelte

Is there a way to pass multiple params into a dynamic route?

For example I have a search result page that is looping through results

```
{#each results as result}
  <a href="../book/{result.key}">
    {result.title}
  </a>
{/each}
```

I am passing the key to a `[slug]` route and I am using the key to call an API.

My end goal is to have the `result.title` be the dynamic route param, but I also want to pass the `result.key` so I am able to call the API.

This post: [Passing mulitple parameters to dynamic route in Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670416/passing-mulitple-parameters-to-dynamic-route-in-svelte) is over a year old and I was wondering if there is now a way to do this and I would like to keep the route as `/title` instead of `/title/key` or `/key/title` as suggested in that post.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to embed both of them somehow in the URL. Perhaps a construction like `/book/<title>?key=<key>` would do for you ? I notice that would be the 'other option' from the post you linked, but the answer there is outdated.

Nowadays you would either in `+page.sveltejs` or `+page.server.js` do

```js
export const load = (async ({ params, url }) => {
  const title = params.title;
  const key = url.searchParams.get('key');
}
```

But here you would have to be aware that `key` could be empty.

One last option (that I personally don't like) is to have the urls in the form of `/book/<title>-<key>`, this is something you sometimes see with product sites.

In this case your file will be called `/book/[title]-[key]/+page.svelte`

And you just extract the params as normal:

```js
export const load = (async ({ params }) => {
  const { key, title } = params;
}
```